# NullPointerException in Java - InputMap, ActionMap

Tags: java, key

I get NullPointerException. What's wrong here?

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private final int WIDTH = 600;
    private final int HEIGHT = 400;
    private InputMap imap = getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    private ActionMap amap;


    public MainPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        makeShortcut("UP", new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                System.out.print("up");
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeShortcut(String keys, AbstractAction action) {
        imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keys), "action"+keys);
        amap.put("action"+keys, action);
    }
}
```

*Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.*

Comment: What's up with that last line?

Comment: Where are you initializing `amap` attribute? Its default value will be `null` (at least for the provided [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Comment: Looking at, or posting the stacktrace would help you (or us) to find the source of the problem more easily.

Answer (score 3):

```
amap.put("action"+keys, action);
```

You've never assigned `amap`, so it has its default value of `null`.  You cannot call instance methods on a null reference.